# validating multiple inputs at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have three text inputs :

- First name
- Last Name
- User Name

In the form I have only these inputs are of type: text.
I want each one of them to be at least 4 characters long so I decided to validate them together.
I want to use Jquery to display an error message that is red when the length is less than 4 and green when it is greater.
I put three error messages respectively with the following Ids:

- flength
- llength
- ulength

(the first letter corresponds to the input , example first name : flength and so on)
so here is my code to do this:

```
$('input [type= text]').keyup(function ({
    var l = $(this).val();
    var x = l.id;
    x = x.charAt(0);
    x = '#' + x + 'length';
    if (l.length < 4) {
        $(x).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $(x).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
});
```

Why wouldn't this script work? what should I modify?
**Edit**
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3yqVg/)

Comment: What do you mean by _"won't work"_.  What happens?  What are your console errors?

Comment: @Sparky you can see the demo right now

Comment: change the 3rd line  to var x = $(this).attr('id'); http://jsfiddle.net/3yqVg/2/

Comment: thank you all for help, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After seeing your comments**

changing `var x = $(this).attr("id");` wont fix the problem too

since `$(this).attr("id")` gives your current element id and your current element is your input tag element and you did not set the `id` attribute, Instead you have set it to `div` tags as you have mentioned in your comments, since you are trying to retrieve id attribute which you have not set and your getting an error.

One solution I could give is this way

```
<input type="text" name="flength"/> // set name attribute same as div ids
<input type="text" name="llength"/>
<input type="text" name="ulength"/>

 $('input[type=text]').keyup(function ({
    var l = $(this).val(); // get the input string
    var x = $(this).attr('name'); // get the current input element name attribute 
    if (l.length < 4) {
        $('#' + x).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $('#' + x).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
});
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Q2y8m/4/

Comment: @user689, What do you mean by _"didn't work"_.  What happens?  What are your console errors?

Comment: @Sparky the error message remains red which means it didn't work. error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined

Comment: @user689, do you think that's something you should be ignoring? _"Cannot call method `charAt` of undefined"_ ~ Focus your efforts, and your OP, on the corresponding line in your code!

Comment: @user689 after seeing your code i have a question do your input elements have ids flength llength or some other elements?

Comment: @Sparky I didn't know about the console error until you asked me to check it, but still I don't know what to do in this case

Comment: @user689, the error message is written plainly enough.  _"Cannot call method `charAt` of undefined"_ means that the object where you've attached the `charAt()` method is not defined or doesn't exist.  Focus efforts on your `x`...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function () {
    var l = $(this).val();
    var x = $(this).attr('id'); // notice it is not l.id
    x = x.charAt(0);
    x = '#' + x + 'length';
    if (l.length < 4) {
        $(x).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $(x).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
});
```

});

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/3yqVg/2/

Comment: I don't want to color the input, I want to color the error message\

Comment: @user689 provide some html code where the error span or div is

Comment: I'm trying to make a Js Fiddle Demo.

Comment: @user689, the code in your posting contains mistakes, but your failure to show a complete example and explain the errors you're getting is causing nothing but confusion.

Comment: @Manish it would not work this.id . the id was not assigned to the input elements but to the li elements

Comment: @niko getting id from input has nothing to do with li. this.id will work fine http://jsfiddle.net/3yqVg/4/

Answer (score -1):

Try to change var `x = l.id;` width var `x = $(this).id;`